# Does Retry in the AWS SDK only work in the Metadata service?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

It was confirmed that the number of retry or the Backoff for each function.
However, in order to actually retry, there needs to be something like a loop statement, [which](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/util.js#L872) seems to be used only in [MetaData](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/metadata_service.js#L87).

When define an AWS module, import `event_listeners`. [It](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/66ac72f2bb52fc714f736c111d012a9002670433/lib/event_listeners.js#L503) looks like there's a corresponding logic there.

Is `event_listeners` middleware for AWS request ? How does it work?